# Get user's real IP address in Cloud9 IDE

Tags: node.js, proxy, http-headers, socket.io, cloud9-ide

In node.js + socket.io I use this code to get user's IP address:

`var clientIP = socket.handshake.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || socket.handshake.address.address;`

But the result is wrong. I `console.log`'d these values and got the following results:

`socket.handshake.address.address` is obviously internal IP (127.x.x.x)

`x-forwarded-for` is one of the cloud9's proxies (107.23.232.64, 54.236.78.114, 107.23.123.140).

So apparently double proxying is used and one of the proxy layers does not provie `'x-forwarded-for'` header, right? Is getting real IP of the user absolutely impossible with cloud9? It is essential for my project.

Comment: you cannot get the user's remote IP with 100% accuracy if they're being proxied somehow. EVERY SINGLE IP you can get from the various http headers is trivially forgeable/changeable. Only $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] is even remotely trustworthy, and even that is only the LAST machine that the user's packets came from before getting to your site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud9 is indeed using a two layer proxy to give access to applications running in workspaces. The first proxy is checking access rights and the second one is tunneling requests to the workspaces. The second proxy is hosted by our infrastructure provider OpenShift and that one overwrites the `x-forwarded-for` header set by the first one. Unfortunately we have no means to fix this at the moment. As mentioned in the comment try to avoid relying on the remote's IP.